# Automatic numbering in Excel with hierarchy

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I would like to do an automatic summary numbering. The only thing we could do is to number the A's (the titles) but the subtitles should be numbered automatically. If the title = 1, subtitle 1.1, below 1.1.1 and so on.

Let's say the titles are A, B and C are subtibles.

The pattern should be like this

> 1.A
>
> 1.1 B
>
> 1.2 B
>
> 2.A
>
> 2.1 B
>
> 2.1.1 C

So I tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32321112/7968011

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJetB.png)

[What we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dk1a.png)

[What we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbH5D.png)

Comment: I don't have any data as an example, but imagine a summary with titles and subtitles.

I would like that by marking the titles with the letter A in a column, the subtitles with the letter B in the same column, the numbering is done by itself.

I think we can simplify the problem by just having titles and a subtitle, if we find a solution for that, we can replicate it for the number of subtitles we want.

Here an example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbH5D.png

Comment: Solution here: https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/excel-gantt-chart.html (column A)

Comment: it's working and they used this formula: =IF(ISERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(prevWBS;".";"")));"1";IF(ISERROR(FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevWBS;".";"`";1)));TEXT(VALUE(prevWBS)+1;"#");TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(prevWBS;FIND("`";SUBSTITUTE(prevWBS;".";"`";1))-1))+1;"#")))

Does someone know the purpose of "prevWBS"?

Comment: Yes. It is quite common scheduling template. I have not posted answer due to good post from @Chronocidal. "prevWBS" is dynamic named range and works like offset from current cell one row up. One could replace it with e.g. `OFFSET(A8,-1,0,1,1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your Level Marker as "A" / "B" / "C" in Column A, and the heading in Column B, then you can use the following (convoluted) code:

```
=REPT(CHAR(9), CODE(A1)-65) & SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))) & "." & IF(CODE(A1)>65,SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="B")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))*--(ROW(A:A)>=MAX(--ROW(A:A)*--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".","") & IF(CODE(A1)>66,SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="C")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))*--(ROW(A:A)>=MAX(--ROW(A:A)*--(A:A="B")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".","") & CHAR(9) & B1
```

Let's break it down into steps:

1. Start with Tabs to indent the heading (0 for "A", 1 for "B", 2 for "C"): `REPT(CHAR(9), CODE(A1)-65)` where `Char(9)` is a Tab.
2. Next, we want to count how many "A"s have we had.  We can use `SUMPRODUCT` to run this as an Array Formula, looking for cells where the value is "A" and the Row is <= current row: `SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1)))`. Shove a dot after that, and you have your heading number.
3. Next, `IF` Column A is "B" or later in the alphabet (`IF(CODE(A1)>65`, since `CODE("A")`=65, `CODE("B")`=66, etc) then we want to count how many "B"s since the last "A".  This is very similar to our last query, but we need a `ROW(A:A)>=LAST_A`.  But, what is `LAST_A`?  Well, we want the `MAX` Row where Column A = "A" and Row <= current row.  So, `MAX(--ROW(A:A)*--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1)))`.
4. This gives `SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="B")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))*--(ROW(A:A)>=MAX(--ROW(A:A)*--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1)))))`

Now, we need to add the `IF` and the full-stop, to get

```
If(Code(A1)>65,SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="B")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))*--(Row(A:A)>=MAX(--ROW(A:A)*--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".","")
```

Repeat the same for all "C"s since the last "B", and then finally add a Tab (`CHAR(9)`) and the value in Column B.

(If you want, for example, 4 spaces or 6 hyphens or 7 dots instead of Tabs at the start of the row or between the number and the tile, just replace the first or last `CHAR(9)`)

**{EDIT}** *Example:*
[image: Example of the formula for 7 rows]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer and especially to explain your formula, it allows me to learn. I put the letters A, B, C in the column A and put your formula in B1. I scrolled it to B20 but nothing is displayed. 

The data are in column A, your formula is in B1 am I right?

Comment: No - put the formula is C1 or D1, and put the text part of the title in column B - E.g. `[[A | Introduction] [B | Premise] [B | Dependencies] [C | This this will affect] [C | Things this is affected by]]` will give the 5th entry as `1.2.2. Things this is affected by`

Comment: Wow, impressive, it works perfectly, thanks for your help Chronocidal. I can't upvote, I don't have enough reputation haha

Comment: But you can accept answer :) I would like only indicate that using whole ranges is usually not the best idea from performance point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty.

Just enter the first section manualy.
Then insert it below:

```
=IF(A3="down",B2&"1.",IF(A3="up",LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-4)&MID(B2,LEN(B2)-3,1)+1&".",LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-2)&MID(B2,LEN(B2)-1,1)+1&"."))
```

When you write "down" it will add "1." in the end of the string above.
When you write "up" it will remove the last 2 chars and add 1 to the last char of the string above.
if you dont write nothing it will add 1 to the last char.

bug: "up" will not work if section is > 9.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the previous answer, here is a solution that will address the problem of sections >9.
The formula is lengthy - but works - and I am sure there will be some smarter way of addressing the problem.

Firstly the structure of the working solution I have.
Column C contains manually entered numbers that represent the levels in the hierarchy e.g., 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 4 4 2 2 3
The top of column B contains the Level 1 number e.g. 1 but could be 10 or 100.

The main formula is placed in column B below the Level 1 number and the formula looks like:

> =IFERROR(IF(C3>C2,B2&"."&1,IF(C2>C3,LEFT(B2,HLOOKUP(C3,Dots,ROW()-2)+HLOOKUP(C3+1,Dots,ROW()-2)-HLOOKUP(C3,Dots,ROW()-2)-2)&MID(B2,HLOOKUP(C3+1,Dots,ROW()-2)-1,1)+1,LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1)&VALUE(RIGHT(B2,1)+1))),"")

The final part of the solution structure is a table containing the positions of the "."s in each string. The first "." is found using

> =IFERROR(FIND(".",B3),"")

The second/ third/fourth dot is found using e.g.

> =IFERROR(FIND(".",$B3,D3+1),"")

Add a header to this "table" with the numbers 2,3,4,5 representing the levels of the hierarchy. Name the table "Dots".

How does it work?
The key to the solution is knowing where the dots are in the previous section. If the sections are limited to <=9 then the dots are always in the even positions. However they move to the right as soon as there is a double or triple digit number.

The formula has 4 sections;
a) Iferror then "". Always keeps the sheet tidy.
b) If the level number increases from one section to the next, then the previous section is supplemented with a ".1"
c) If the level number remains the same, the the last character is incremented (value) by 1.
d) If the level decreases (the complex part) the HLookup takes information from the table to reduce the previous section string back to the new level and add the incremental section number.

[Working Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8kji.png)