# How to start from 0 using ROW()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

So I have this formula [source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027029/automatic-numbering-in-excel-with-hierarchy)

`=REPT(CHAR(9); CODE(A1)-65) & SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="A")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1)-1)) & "." & IF(CODE(A1)>65;SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="B")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)>=MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$200)*($A$1:$A$200="A")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".";"") & IF(CODE(A1)>66;SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="C")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)>=MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$200)*($A$1:$A$200="B")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".";"") & CHAR(9) & B1`

Which give us this:

[image]

The question is: How do I start from 0?

Starting from zero mean, 
`Title 1 = 0. Title 1`
`Title 2 = 1. Title 2`
`Subtitle 3 = 1.1 Subtitle 3`

Just found the solution, you need too `Subtract 1 from the first SUMPRODUCT`

Thanks for you help everyone

`=REPT(CHAR(9); CODE(A1)-65) & SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="A")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1)))-1 & "." & IF(CODE(A1)>65;SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="B")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)>=MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$200)*($A$1:$A$200="A")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".";"") & IF(CODE(A1)>66;SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="C")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)>=MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$200)*($A$1:$A$200="B")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1))))) & ".";"") & CHAR(9) & B1`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with *start from 0*?

Comment: Like this `ROW(A:A)-1`?

Comment: Like: `ROW(A1)-1`? I'm also not entirely sure what you are asking here. You have a VERY complex formula and you only ask that you "start from 0 using Row()" . Just start from 0 then.. whatever that means.

Comment: Find the spots where it says `& "."`, then slip in a `- 1` before that (possibly parenthesizing the subexpression first). No understanding of how it works required.

Comment: You also do not need all the `--` if you are going to multiply others to it.  the `--` is only needs it the boolean expression is by itself.

Comment: Starting from zero mean, 
`Title 1 = 0. Title 1`
`Title 2 = 1. Title 2`
`Subtitle 3 = 1.1 Subtitle 3`

Comment: At this part, just subtract one? `...SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="A")*--(ROW(A:A)<=ROW(A1)))-1`...  Edit: I think you updated the formula..try here, `SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$200="A")*(ROW($A$1:$A$200)<=ROW(A1)-1))-1`?

Comment: Almost Bruce, I should have 0 for Introduction

`Introduction "-1. Introduction"`
`Subtitle " 0.1. Subtitle"`
`Sub  "  0.1.1. Sub "`

Comment: Subtract 1 from the first `SUMPRODUCT`.  For reference, the formula is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027029/automatic-numbering-in-excel-with-hierarchy) and the part to edit is bullet-point **2.**

Answer (score 0):

In general, to create a column of values starting from zero and increasing by one, pick any cell and enter:

```
=ROWS($1:1)-1
```

and copy downward.